# iPhone : How to get each element from QR code vCard?

Tags: iphone, parsing, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I am developing one simple application which is used to read the QR code vCard and display the details of the contact information in the QR code vCard. I am able to scan the vCard and get the details about the contact as follows

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:XX;XXXXXXXX
FN:XXXXXXXXX XX
TEL;WORK;VOICE:91999999999
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:sac@gmail.com
END:VCARD
```

But I need to parse each element in it. How to parse the details and what are the ways to parse?

Comment: we need some code how to fetch this info means code fo QR code which you are used.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I am using Zbar sdk for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation points to this method:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    for(symbol in results){

        NSString *upcString = symbol.data;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scanned UPC" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The UPC read was: %@", upcString] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

        [alert show];

        [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];    
    }
```

}

i would first see what it returns maybe try looping the dictionary for additional data

Comment: It will show same as I said in my question. BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:XX;XXXXXXXX
FN:XXXXXXXXX XX
TEL;WORK;VOICE:91999999999
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:sac@gmail.com
END:VCARD

Comment: BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:Peter;;;; FN: Peter TITLE:CEO ORG:qrd°by URL;WORK:qrd.by EMAIL;INTERNET:peter@qrd.by END:VCARD Above string get when i scan QRCode. Now i have to show auto filled contact form like this. see the url. https://blog.qrd.by/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/vcard-qr-code.jpg Please help

Answer (score 1):

Well its being quite a long time that this question is asked. But answering now might also help someone who is navigated to this page. You can use the below method for reference to parse the VCF data.

```
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:response.vcfString];
    NSArray *subStrings = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet      characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n"]];
    NSArray *getData = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    NSString *arr = @"";

    for (int i=0;i<[subStrings count];i++)
    {
        arr = [subStrings objectAtIndex:i];

        NSArray *abc = [arr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]];

        if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"FN"])
        {
            getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"] ];

            if([getData count] > 1)
            fullName = [getData objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"N"])
        {
            getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

            if([getData count] > 1)
            lastName = [getData objectAtIndex:1];
            FirstName = [abc objectAtIndex:2];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"TITLE"])
        {
            getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

            if([getData count] > 1)
            title = [getData objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"TEL"])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            if([abc count] == 3)
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([[abc objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"WORK"])
                {
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                        [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Tel"];
                }
                else if([[abc objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"CELL"])
                {
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                        [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Tel"];
                }
            }
            else if([abc count] == 4)
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:3] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([[abc objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"WORK"] && [[abc objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"FAX"])
                {
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                        [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Tel"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([[getData objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"WORK"])
                {
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                        [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Tel"];
                }
                else if([[getData objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"FAX"])
                {
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                        [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Tel"];
                }
            }
            [_telList addObject:dict];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"EMAIL"])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            if([abc count] == 3)
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([[abc objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"WORK"])
                {
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                        [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Email"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([getData count] > 1)
                    [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Email"];
            }
            [_emailList addObject:dict];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"ORG"])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            if([abc count] == 5)
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([[abc objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"WORK"])
                {
                    NSString *orgStr = @"";
                    if([getData count] > 1)
                    {
                        orgStr = [getData objectAtIndex:1];
                    }
                    [dict setObject:[orgStr stringByAppendingString:[abc objectAtIndex:4]] forKey:@"Org"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([getData count] > 1)
                    [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Org"];
            }
            [_orgList addObject:dict];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"ADR"])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            if([abc count] == 9)
            {
                [dict setObject:[abc objectAtIndex:4] forKey:@"Add"];
                [dict setObject:[abc objectAtIndex:8] forKey:@"Country"];
                [dict setObject:[abc objectAtIndex:7] forKey:@"Zip"];
                [dict setObject:[abc objectAtIndex:5] forKey:@"City"];
            }
            else
            {

            }

            [_addrList addObject:dict];
        }
        else if([[abc objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"URL"])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            if([abc count] == 3)
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([getData count] > 1)
                    [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Url"];
            }
            else
            {
                getData=[[abc objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"]];

                if([getData count] > 1)
                    [dict setObject:[getData objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"Url"];
            }

            [_urlList addObject:dict];
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }


    NSLog(@"Details:  \nFull Name - %@\nLast Name - %@\nFirst Name - %@\ntitle - %@\nEmail - %@\norg - %@\nAddress - %@\nUrl - %@", fullName,lastName,FirstName,title,[[_emailList valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""],[_orgList description],[_addrList description],[_urlList description] );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Encoder of QRCode

[Encoder](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CNContactVCardSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactvcardserialization) to get `CNContact` Object from data

```
import Contacts
   if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
       do {
          let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: data)
          let contact = contacts.first
          print("\(String(describing: contact?.familyName))")
          return contact
       } catch {
          print("Contact Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }
    }
```

Comment: BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Peter;;;;
FN: Peter 
TITLE:CEO
ORG:qrd°by
URL;WORK:https://qrd.by
EMAIL;INTERNET:peter@qrd.by
END:VCARD

Above string get when i scan QRCode. Now i have to show auto filled contact form like this. see the url. https://blog.qrd.by/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/vcard-qr-code.jpg Please help

Comment: @Ashu. I think apple doesn't provided any public APIs to show Default Contact Form. Currently we have to create it manually.

Comment: But another app is also doing this

Comment: Try [CNContactViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactviewcontroller)